Adding an egg to “peasant bread” dough
I've been making various variations of peasant (no-kneed) bread for the past several months (see https://alexandracooks.com/2012/11/07/my-mothers-peasant-bread-the-best-easiest-bread-you-will-ever-make/)
I'm generally happy with the results but would like to have my bread turn out a bit softer on the inside.
I've read that adding an egg to bread dough will help with that because of how the fats interact with the bread proteins.
Just wondering if anyone has tried this. How did it work out?
Do I need to have any special considerations about proofing dough with a raw egg in it?

You can also just straight up add fat.  I use the ‘Olive oil dough’ from the book ‘artisan bread in 5 minutes a day’

I don’t have that book but I like that idea. I’m going to try a recipe I found with olive oil
